# gcc atomic extension for storing and incrementing

Tags: gcc, atomic

Does there exist any gcc extensions to atomically do an operation like

a = b++ in C. Using a mutex seems to be an overkill for such a trivial operation.

Comment: A quick Google search turned up [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html#_005f_005fsync-Builtins) among the first entries.

Comment: I did have a look at that web page but it doesnt help for my query. You can do a (b++) operation atomically using those extensions but to do a = b++ is not given in that page.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use any extensions; just use `<stdatomic.h>`:

```
#include <stdatomic.h>

atomic_store(&a, atomic_fetch_add(&b, 1));
```

Comment: It looks as if individually atomic_store and atomic_fetch_add are atomic, but would they together be atomic too?

Comment: @mc_87 that depends what you mean by "atomic"; but as the default ordering is sequential consistency, and a dependency chain exists from `b` to `a`, you are guaranteed that no other thread can see the new value of `a` along with the previous value of `b`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: I am sorry, I should I have given more details. Here a is a private variable and b is a shared variable.